# Kotlin: appendText and closing resources

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin, but I have a strong Java background (Java is my day job). I'm loving some of the shortcut functions in Kotlin. One of the big ones is File.appendText(). It's very convenient, in my opinion.

My question is about closing resources. If I was to use a writer, I would do something like this:

```
out8.writer().use { ... }
```

But I don't see any thing directly on the appendText method that indicates closing resources. Does Kotlin handle this behind the scenes for me, or is this something I have to worry about in another way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just jump into the implementation of `appendText` in your IDE to find out (`Ctrl + B` on Windows, `⌘B` on Mac).

Here's the implementation of the method:

```
public fun File.appendText(text: String, charset: Charset = Charsets.UTF_8): Unit 
    = appendBytes(text.toByteArray(charset))
```

And here's the `appendBytes` method that it delegates the work to:

```
public fun File.appendBytes(array: ByteArray): Unit 
    = FileOutputStream(this, true).use { it.write(array) }
```

You can see that it actually uses the [`use`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html) helper method as you've expected.

Answer (score 1):

You are right there is no `appendText` function on `Writer`, you can see [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-writer/index.html) as further.

The [use](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#java-7s-try-with-resources) function is same as java-7 *try-with-resource* expression. it will close the resource after the block exit. In fact, [File#appendText](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/append-text.html) call the [use](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/idioms.html#java-7s-try-with-resources) function to close the resource.

**IF** you append the text only once you can using [File#appendText](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/append-text.html) instead. for example:

```
out8.appendText("content")
```

**IF** you want to operate a file more than once, you should using the [File#bufferedWriter()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/buffered-writer.html) instead, since the [File#appendText](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/append-text.html) will create & open a new writer each time. for example:

```
out8.bufferedWriter().use{ 
    it.append("first").append("second") 
}
```

Comment: The first paragraph of the question states that the question is about `File.appendText()`

Comment: thanks for you feedback. I know it. I just point it out what's he misunderstand. :)